# Why is deadpools cancer not healed like it was supppose to be?

Tags: character, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool

The question I am looking for is, why didn't his healing factor kill the cancer cells. **Isn't it strong enough to kill them.** Why did his cancer cells stay?

Comment: What?? If his healing abilities didn't cure the cancer, how was he still alive? He should have been dead already ... not sure what this question is about, because it doesn't follow the movie I watched. Are you talking about how his skin looked?

Comment: Related: [Why doesn't a healing factor cure cancer?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12929/why-doesnt-a-healing-factor-cure-cancer)

Comment: Where does it say his cancer wasn't cured?